# How to convert a ecore File to a ecorediag File

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf-ecore

I build a DSL by use xtext. And i can find the  ecore file of my DSL ,which generate by xtext. 
Right now i want  convert this ecore File to a ecorediag File.Is this possible?Which tools shoule i use?

Comment: I have the same problem, the conversion function of emf models to diagrams is missing in my eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

- With eclipse update manager install  EMF - Eclipse Modeling Framework SDK and ecore tools SDK.
- And then file -> new -> ecore tools -> Ecore diagram
- In the wizard select create from an existing model and browse to your existing ecore file.

For installation of plug-ins instructions with the update manager please look [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#plugin_installation).

Answer (score 1):

Right click to your ecore file and select "initialize ecore diagram" then select design->entities. You will get an empty diagram saying double click here to load at the left top. Double click there and it will load your ecore to a diagram.